# Visual Studio Code подсказки

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

У меня есть один и тот же проект открытый в WebStorm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И WebStorm видит методы, которые находятся в библиотеках подключенных через `import` в данном случае он видит `dispatch`.
Так вот, вопрос состоит в то, что можно настроить в Visual Studio Code чтоб он тоже видел методы из `import`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`VS Code` даже не представляет о существовании `dispatch`.

Comment: Была такая проблема. Как бы не банально, но помогла переустановка :)